# Why is nginx redirecting assets to home page?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I got the same nginx config in development and in production, and the production server keeps re-directing assets links (and only assets links) to home page. Other links, that are served by blade view route are fine.

So a link to `https://subdomain.example.com/test` will work fine, providing there is a view in the routes of Laravel.

But, a link to `https://subdomain.example.com/img/picture-of-a-cat.png` will be redirected back to home screen, but the address bar will still show `https://subdomain.example.com/img/picture-of-a-cat.png`. This behaviour is only observed in production.

Sever details: Ubuntu 18.4, Nginx, Laravel latest

Where is the catch?

Production config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name subdomain.example.com
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;

        root /var/www/html/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example-cert.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example-private-key.key;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
   location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the full path of `picture-of-a-cat.png`? Does the file exist? Can the Nginx user access the file and all the directories above it?

Comment: Hi, I changed the full path to ```https://subdomain.example.com/img/picture-of-a-cat.png``` and the server path is ```/var/www/html/public/img/picture-of-a-cat.png```. The file does exist. Also the structure in the blade template is: ```<a href=(link)><img src=(link)><a>```. Public folder got ```ubuntu www-data``` and ```-rw-r--r-- ``` permissions.

Comment: The permissions for all folders need to give read access. Check the access log and error log.